# Creating Windows-style system tabs using CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I am trying to create a set of tabs like what you'd find in a dialog box in Windows,  where each tab links to a different 'panel' of information. As you may know, the key features of these types of tabs are that a) they auto-stretch to fit both their contents and the width of the container, and b) they do this regardless of the number of tabs (i.e. they can be created dynamically).

So far, I have managed to create this:

[image: Tabs made from tables]

This is created using several `<table>` elements. I am looping through the tabs (SQL/PHP), and when the number of tabs reaches 5, the table tag is closed and a new table is created. So in the screenshot above, there are 3 tables (I found this easier than trying to get divs to replicate this behaviour). When you click a tab, it's corresponding parent table is moved to the bottom of the 'set'.

While this is working quite well, I would like to have the table columns (`<th>`) stretch to fit in a nicer way (for example I would expect tabs 'Test 6' and 'Test7' to be equal in width).

The table code looks like this:

```
table.tabs_grey {
    text-align: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

table.tabs_grey > thead > tr > th:last-child {
    width: 1%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

table.tabs_grey > thead > tr > th.active > div {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #4C758A;
    background: #5292B3;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FCFCFC;
    cursor: default;
}

table.tabs_grey > thead > tr > th.inactive > div {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #bebebe;
    background: #EBEBEB url('Images/gui.shade.trans.24.png');
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #4e4e4e;
    cursor: default;
    border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

If I remove the "width: 1%;", I get this:

[image: Tabs made from tables]

Is there a way to achieve the kind of spacing I have described? I'm sure the way I've done it is a bit crazy, so any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.